# AUCTeX indenting after ampersands

Tags: auctex

I don't know what AUCTeX thinks it's doing here, but I don't like it:

```
\begin{align}
  a &= b
      + c
\end{align}
```

I can sort of see that maybe it thinks the `+c` should "go with" the `= b`.  But the following case seems obviously wrong to me:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &= b &\qquad
           c &= d
\end{alignat}
```

This seems to be a recent change (at least, I don't think it used to do that on my old computer).  How can I turn it off?

Comment: Everything you described seems OK for me. AUCTeX simply aligns content around `&`. If you want to customise it, you could disable `eletrci-indent-mode` (see the [discussion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-to-disable-auto-indentation-of-new-lines)) or perhaps you want to alter how <kbd>RETURN</kbd> behaves in AUCTeX (info about it [here](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Indenting)).

Comment: @Celdor I don't want AUCTeX to "align content around `&`".  Does that second example really look correct to you?  I want to keep general electric-indent and the behavior of return for other contexts, I just want to change the treatment of `&`.

Comment: I'm no math expert, but the input seems strange to me. Shouldn't there be ``\\`` at the end of the line? Shouldn't the number of `&` in each line match? Doesn't `alignat` take an argument?

Comment: @gusbrs Sorry, I forgot the argument of `alignat`.  There's only one line of output in that example, with two equations separated by a space.  But I want the two equations on different lines in the source, without the second one being indented way to the end of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only presume that you don't have such a line in your init file:

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Hence, you didn't get this behavior which was actually always there, in the AUCTeX file `amsmath.el` but it was not activated.

At any rate, have a look at the variable `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` which has entries like:

```el
("align" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
("alignat" LaTeX-indent-tabular)
```

Customize this variable and remove the environment names where you don't want this sort of indentation.  This variable was changed with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=ddb0f08ff1adb8a89f2d808dd6109ed535e552b3).

---

Say you have a file `phd-thesis.tex` which looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

When you have set `TeX-parse-self` to `nil` (which is also the default value) and load this file, the value of `TeX-active-styles` is `("phd-thesis" "LATEX")`.  This means that AUCTeX will only load a (auto-parsed) file `phd-thesis.el` if it finds one in the `./auto` subdirectory.  If you've never parsed the file before (with <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>), there is no `./auto/phd-thesis.el`.  So basically you can't take advantage of the extensions AUCTeX provides in `geometry.el` and `natbib.el`.

When you have set `TeX-parse-self` to `t` and there is no `./auto/phd-thesis.el`, AUCTeX parses the file (but doesn't write a `./auto/phd-thesis.el)` and the value of `TeX-active-styles` is now `("natbib" "geometry" "art10" "article" "latex2e" "phd-thesis" "LATEX")`.  This means that AUCTeX has loaded its extensions.  If there is a `./auto/phd-thesis.el`, AUCTeX loads that file and doesn't re-parse the file.

Here is the relevant part from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#Parsing-Files).

I suggest a setting like this:

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)  ; Enable parse on load
(setq TeX-auto-save nil) ; Disable parse on save
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it!  Thanks.  What does TeX-parse-self do?  The docstring is rather telegraphic.

Comment: @MikeShulman - See the updated answer.